# HDD short DST fail. How to know the reason?

Tags: hard-drive, storage

I used the Seagate hdd tool and run a Short Drive Self Test a Western Digital disk. It says "Short DST FAIL", but that is the only information. How do I know what exactly failed? I mean, the spindle motor, the PCB, the platter, the header, what? I don't have to use the Seagate tool, if there is another tool that could tell me what exactly failed, I would like to know.

[image]

Comment: Obtain the SMART values before and after a test, and compare them.

Comment: try a third party utility like crystaldiskinfo info or speedfan or whatever to check your SMART stats. IIRC you can run SMART tests via speedfan. that said, be prepared to replace the disk if you care about the data and don't have a solid backup plan. the potential risk is quite real.